# Linq - return all when filter is blank

Tags: c#, linq, search

I have a Linq query that returns a set of products based on a multi-word search entered by the user. This works fine when something is entered into the search box but when nothing is entered, no products are returned. I'd like the Linq to return all records when searchby is blank but so far haven't figured it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    public ActionResult ProductListMain(string category, int? page, string searchby)
{
    searchby = searchby ?? "";

    List<string> searchList = searchby.Split(' ').ToList();

    JJDEntities db = new JJDEntities();

    var products = db.Products
       .Where(p => p.Category.Name == category
              && p.Active == true
              && !searchList.Any(s => !p.Keywords.Contains(s)))
       .Include(p => p.Category)
       .OrderBy(p => p.Description)
       .ThenBy(p => p.Name);

    List<ProductViewModel> productsVM = new List<ProductViewModel>();
    foreach (Product product in products)
    {
        ProductViewModel pvm = new ProductViewModel()
        {
            ProductID = product.ProductID,
            Name = product.Name,
            Description = product.Description,
            Keywords = product.Keywords,
            ImagePath = product.ImagePath,
            ThumbnailPath = product.ThumbnailPath,
            CategoryID = product.CategoryID,
            Price = product.Price,
            Active = product.Active,
            ProductStatusID = product.Status,
            Category = product.Category

        };
        productsVM.Add(pvm);
    }
    return View(productsVM.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 15));
}
```

Comment: You can treat something inside Where like `&& !searchList.Any(s => !p.Keywords.Contains(s) || searchList.Count() == 0 || searchList == null)`. You can make sure that if ther is not any work typed.

Comment: Just say `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( searchby ) || !searchList.Any(s => !p.Keywords.Contains(s))) )`. Does it actually make sense to have that double negotiation? Why not use `searchList.Any(s => p.Keywords.Contains(s))`